# Declare a empty array in python

Tags: python, arrays, is-empty

I'm changing python code where the value for settings that are declared in the python code are read from a json file the main question is one of the setting values is an array of strings

Example (json file):

```
"list_of_names": {"names": ["Peter", "James"]} and i´m trying not to declare any value so it will be: "list_of_names": {[]}
```

When I read this value on the python code example: `list_of_names(names=Ilist["names"])` , I need that he accept the empty array with no value, and move to the next setting. How can I implement this?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is the meaning of `llist`? Is `list_of_names` a dictionary (your first reference) or a key in a dictionary (also your first reference) or a function (your last reference)? In your second reference, are you trying to make `list_of_names` to be an empty dictionary? What do you mean by " i need that he accept the empty array whit no value, and move to the next setting"? Please clarify. It would greatly help if you show the context by providing [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
.

Comment: thanks for your replay i will try to explain better :)

Comment: Also please use the code formater for code snippets and (for python code) make sure it's correctly indented (indentation is part of python syntax, it's not just cosmetic).

Comment: thanks i think have i formatted correctly the examples this time

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

# Create an empty array
x = np.empty((3,4))

print(x)

# Create a full array
y = np.full((3,3),6)

print(y)
```

This is the Code to create an empty array in pyhton..

And the use of numpy as np is this:

1. numpy is a general-purpose array-processing package. It provides a high-performance multidimensional array object, and tools for working with these arrays.
2. `x=np.empty((3,4))` this statement is used to create an array with the size of (3,4) and the values of an array will be empty. and `print(x)` will print the Values of an Array that is Garbage Value will be Printed
3. `y = np.full((3,3),6)` this statement is used to crate an array with the size of (3,3) and the value of an array will be 6. and the `print(y)` statement will print the values of an Array

Comment: tanks for your replay, but i thinks that not it, the main objective is that the array can be empty

Comment: The Array cannot be empty because the Array will have a Garbage values ...